# MPRemoteCommandCenter play/pause command not updating properly

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, carplay, mpremotecommandcenter

I have set play/pause button enabled and also added target event to each but when ever I click button in simulator it always calls play button's target event and button's image not properly updating from play to pause and vice versa. Any one have idea regards this?

> Note: To play/pause audio I have used Plugin.MediaManager.Forms nuget (version 0.9.7)

```
[Export("playableContentManager:initiatePlaybackOfContentItemAtIndexPath:completionHandler:")]
public override void InitiatePlaybackOfContentItem(MPPlayableContentManager contentManager, NSIndexPath indexPath, Action<NSError> completionHandler)
{
    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndReceivingRemoteControlEvents();
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();

        var song = CarPlaylist[indexPath.Section].episodes[indexPath.Row];
        var NowPlayingInfoCenter = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.DefaultCenter;

        MPNowPlayingInfo playingInfo = new MPNowPlayingInfo();
        playingInfo.Title = song.Title;
        playingInfo.Artist = song.Editor;
        playingInfo.PlaybackDuration = song.Duration.TotalSeconds; //provide time in seconds
        playingInfo.MediaType = MPNowPlayingInfoMediaType.Audio;
        playingInfo.Artwork = new MPMediaItemArtwork(image: ExtractArtWork.UIImageFromUrl(song.ArtWork));
        playingInfo.AssetUrl = new NSUrl(song.FileUrl.AbsolutePath);
        playingInfo.PlaybackRate = song.IsPlaying ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        NowPlayingInfoCenter.NowPlaying = playingInfo;

        var currentPlayItemId = episode.PodcastId.ToString();
        string[] identifier = new string[1];
        identifier[0] = currentPlayItemId;

        contentManager = MPPlayableContentManager.Shared;
        contentManager.NowPlayingIdentifiers = identifier;
        contentManager.DataSource = new AppDelegateDataSource(CarPlaylist);

        var commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.Shared;
        commandCenter.PlayCommand.Enabled = true;
        commandCenter.PauseCommand.Enabled = true;
        commandCenter.PlayCommand.AddTarget(PlayButton);
        commandCenter.PauseCommand.AddTarget(PauseButton);

        completionHandler(null);

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndReceivingRemoteControlEvents();
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginReceivingRemoteControlEvents();
    });
}

public MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus PlayButton(MPRemoteCommandEvent commandEvent)
{
    //Logic to update app UI to play mode and play audio
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.Success;
}

public MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus PauseButton(MPRemoteCommandEvent commandEvent)
{
    //Logic to update app UI to pause mode and pause audio
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.Success;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you could have a try with a physical device to check that whether it can work.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, but actually my CarPlay Entitlement process is still in progress, so without getting that I can not test it in real device.